# Right way to populate html form elements from JSON api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an API returning a JSON object containing user settings. Before using it, I was used to filling fields with php:

```
 <input type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked ?>>
```

Now I have a JSON object and no PHP output. How to manipulate it to do the same?

I thought about using jquery to fill in elements on document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').attr('checked', jsonobj.checked);
}
```

But something tells me that it's a bit hackish, is that the right way to do it?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at a front-end templating framework like Mustache.js or Handlebars.js.

Comment: @raphadko is the JSON being returned server-side or client-side?

Comment: client side.. I'm still using PHP server side, but detaching the client side from it

Comment: if the form controls already exist then i'm not sure how front end templating will help

Comment: anyone care to explain?

Comment: Ah, if you already have your form fields in the DOM, you're not far off on how to update -- if you can provide some details on the structure of your JSON & HTML we can suggest some cleaner functions to apply the settings.

Comment: Where does `jsonobj` come from?

Comment: it's outputted inside a javascript block, from php

Comment: If the PHP has the data that becomes `jsonobj` then I do not understand why you cannot echo out that data to populate your form fields. The only reason you would have to populate your fields from JavaScript is if, for some reason, you get the form data *after* page load.